# R Shiny: export plot as png/jpg

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

How to export plot_ly image as png from shiny app? I want to export png or jpg on action button 'ExportPlot' (as specified below). I know about plot_ly solution https://plot.ly/r/static-image-export/ however it require to create user on plot_ly as i read about it.

I would be grateful for any tips/solution.

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton('ExportPlot', 'Export as png'),
  plotlyOutput("plot"),
  verbatimTextOutput("event")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  # renderPlotly() also understands ggplot2 objects!
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(mtcars, x = ~mpg, y = ~wt)
  })

  output$event <- renderPrint({
    d <- event_data("plotly_hover")
    if (is.null(d)) "Hover on a point!" else d
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution which provides download on click:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(
  downloadButton('ExportPlot', 'Export as png'),
  plotlyOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  # generate the plot
  thePlot <- reactive({
    p <- plot_ly(mtcars, x = ~mpg, y = ~wt)
  })

  # renderPlotly() 
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    thePlot()
  })

  # download
  output$ExportPlot <- downloadHandler(
    # file name
    filename <- 'plot.png',
    # content
    content = function(file){
      # create plot
      export(p = thePlot(), file = 'tempPlot.png')
      # hand over the file
      file.copy('tempPlot.png',file)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Please note: With the RStudio browser/viewer the file name which is set per default is not correctly hand over, with external Browsers (e.g. Firefox) it should work.